# Is there a better alternative for the MySQL query below?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The execution of the following MySQL query often takes 2-3 minutes. The objective is to select records from a table, where 2 of it's columns' values are also contained in an other, previously created temporary table. This table has only one column. This temporary table is created instead of 2 subqueries, because 4 tables are needed to be joined in order to get the values.
The temporary table holds around 40 000 records in general, the values are of type `varchar(32) COLLATE 'utf8mb4_bin'`, the `table1` table has 45 000 records.

```
table1
a     |  varchar(32)
b     |  varchar(32)

temp
name  |  varchar(32)
```

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp AS SELECT name FROM names ...;
SELECT a, b 
FROM table1 
WHERE a IN (SELECT name FROM temp) 
  AND b IN (SELECT name FROM temp);
```

`a` and `b` columns of `table1` are indexed.

How to improve the execution speed? Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an index to the `temp` table:

```
ALTER TABLE temp ADD INDEX (name);
```

Also use `JOIN` rather than `IN`. MySQL generally optimizes this better.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN temp AS t2 ON t1.a = t2.name
JOIN temp AS t3 ON t1.b = t3.name
```